# Why is mysql running when i am not using it?

Tags: mysql, taskmanager

I have used mySQL for a project in the past, and haven't used it for months. However, when i check my task manager 'mysql' is using about 100MB of RAM. This happens every times i reboot. Why is my sql running, or using memory when i don't need it. Is a server running in the background that i have to disable? For context i was using my SQL Workbench 8.0 when working on my project.

[image: mysql running on my computer]

Comment: `Is a server running in the background` in short, yes! MySql is a server, running all the time, unless you install it "on-demand" and run and stop it yourself. MySql Workbench is nothing but a client that connects to a server, it has nothing to do with the server itself.

Comment: I see, wow it's been running all this time. Well i am starting a new project and will probably use firebase. Can you provide more details on how to terminate the server. I still want MySQL installed tho in case i need it... or do i have to uninstall it to stop it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may stop the service, set it to disabled so that it never runs as a service. Then you simply run `mysqld.exe` manually when you need to, and close its console when no longer need it.

Comment: Thank you for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Open a command prompt window `cmd.exe`
- Stop MySQL service: `net stop mysql57` (or `net stop mysql`)
- Go to your mysql server installation path, in my case: `cd "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin\"`
- Execute `mysqld.exe --remove`

This will remove the MySQL Service.

Note that You may need an elevated command line prompt, for that press `WIN-X` select `Command Prompt (Admin)`

Answer (score 4):

Yes, MySQL Server service would be constantly running in the background, if (because) this service's startup type was set on an "*automatic start when computer starts*" mode during the installation of MySQL Workbench. The comment by @Alejandro offers the finest explanation.

(below steps I had tried for **MySQL 8.0.30** version, however shall work with nearby versions as well; as steps to stop the service might be generic.)

In Windows 10, to **stop the MySQL Server's service**, OR, **change the *startup-type* setting of MySQL Server.**

- Open `Windows Services` panel via the Start menu, OR, `Win+R` -> type `services.msc`, do Enter.
- Different Windows OS's services would be listed here, alphabetically.
- Find the MySQL Service. For MySQL 8 versions, it's often by default name - `MySQL80`, unless you had named it by a custom name during installation.

[image: find mysql-server service]

- Click STOP, to stop the service.
- On the other hand, you may choose your desired **Startup type**. By default, you'll find it on Automatic type.
- If you want to keep *Manual* type, make sure to start the service by coming at this Services wizard, before using MySQL Workbench. Otherwise, the workbench won't be able to recognize/find the server.

[image: edit startup type]

Answer (score 1):

While installing the MYSQL Server, this check box is by default checked [image](shown in the picture). If you uncheck this, then you need to start your MYSQL Server manually.